# Odoo V10 - Translation file

Tags: python, odoo

there is something I do not understand in the translation files.

Here is what I did:

I start by exporting a translation file 'fr.po' via the Odoo interface. It was enough for me to translate the English of my "string" in French.
In my project, I then create an i18n folder and include my 'fr.po' file with the translations. I update my module, and I see that the translations are done. (Great that's what I wanted! :))

I notice that I have two or three translations to edit. I modify them, and there, although I update my module, impossible to see my translation changes. I do not understand why my file was taken into account at the beginning but more after? Do you have an idea ?

cordially

Comment: Yes it's a bit tricky and sometimes annoying too. Try to reload your browser tab with new or empty cache (in chrome SHIFT + F5). If that doesn't work, reload the translation and override old translations. You will find an extra menu in the translation menu for that.

Comment: The second solution is working. thank you very much